# What did the Origami Chicken and the Matchstick Man represent in "Blade Runner"?

Tags: analysis, blade-runner

In Blade Runner, Gaff is a rather dark, mysterious figure, who throughout the film, lays down 3 pieces origami - a paper chicken, a matchstick man, and a unicorn made of gum-wrappers. The unicorn is a subtle hint at Deckard being a replicant all along, but what did the other two represent?

Now, just to recap, Gaff puts down the chicken in the scene where Deckard refuses to help Bryant with the case. This makes partial sense to me, as Gaff was trying to imply Deckard was chickening out, although this seems very implausible. He puts down the matchstick man after Deckard investigates Leon's house. Deckard seems to gaze at it in confusion, or maybe even recognizance like he did with the unicorn.

I'm gonna make the bold claim that people are so invested into the unicorn that they easily ignore the two predecessors. What do these two creations in particular represent?

[*FACT*: Neither of these two origami was in the original script by Fancher and Peoples.]